# OpenStack: Too many Database idle Connections

Tags: postgresql, openstack, nova

I use PostgreSQL as a DB backend for all OpenStack Services on 3 Controllers. When all 3 controllers are started with no load, the number of connections are up to 700. And all of this conns are in idle mode.

Here are the Database parameters in Openstack service conf files:

```
max_overflow = 50
max_pool_size = 5
pool_timeout = 30
connection_recycle_time = 600
```

I have changed this parameter to smaller values, but it has not improved anything.

Any ideas why the number of connections are too high?

Comment: Is the number of connections actually a problem if they're all idle?

Comment: Kindof, they do use up a bit of RAM

Comment: Are you short on RAM?